# Python Problem with generating a list with information from another list

Tags: python, list, generate

I want to generate a list with python that is based on information from another list. Following example should demonstrate what information I want to transfer:

Following list is given:

```
list_a=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0]
```

Then, the list that I want to generate should look like this:

```
list_b=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,5,4,3,2,1,0,0,0]
```

I started like this:

```
list_b=[]
list_b = [0] * list_a.__len__()         #create a list of nulls
for i in range (list_a.__len__()):
       if list_a(i)!=0:
            if list_a(i+1)=0:
                 list_b.insert(i-(list_a[i]-1),list_a[i])
```

But then I have only inserted the first element to list_b and still need to insert all following elements (e.g. inserted 4 and still need to insert 3,2,1) and the solution/code seems to be too messy.

Anyone knows an elegant solution?

Comment: So you want to keep the zeros in the same location and reverse the non-zero integers?

Comment: _I want to generate a list with python that is based on information from another list._ What does that mean, exactly? How can we help you with a task we know practically nothing about?! _#create a list of nulls_ If you want to represent something like null, use None.

Comment: @AMC Clearly null here doesn't mean None but zero (understandable, especially when one is from Germany).

Comment: @StefanPochmann You're probably right, yeah.

Comment: @AMC I‘m sorry I meant zero, not null! I hope this information is enough to understand the rest of the task

Comment: @chrispresso, exactly

Comment: @Yasmin Can you provide a bit more context for this? I can’t really think of any situation where this kind of operation would be necessary.

Comment: @AMC the list is an input for a Gurobi model and I need it in this form. Each element represents a time period and it describes the amount of time periods that a car is/will be available at a certain place.

Comment: @Lana It's just difficult to tell if there is a better way of doing things because the list of numbers and zeros example feels bizarre and contrived.

Comment: In case you're not aware of it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Group by zeroness and reverse each group.

```
>>> [x for _, g in itertools.groupby(list_a, bool) for x in list(g)[::-1]]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I like your groupby solution. +1. Here is another way to flatten a list of list:    

sum([[*g[1]][::-1] for g in groupby(list_a, bool)], [])

Comment: @VladBezden Yeah, I wrote a `sum` version as well, but I don't like it enough to justify the inefficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure about it's elegancy/efficency, but the following is your solution:

```
list_a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0]
list_b = []
reverse_list = []

for i in list_a:
    if i == 0:
        if reverse_list:
            list_b += reverse_list[::-1]
            reverse_list.clear()
        list_b.append(i)
    else:
        reverse_list.append(i)
# If list ended without encountering zero
list_b += reverse_list[::-1]

print(list_a)
print(list_b)
```

Outputs as:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I'm a beginner and this helps me a lot